# FormClose Event handler when form wasn't opened from parent

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

I have many instances in my program where in the main form1, I call another form2 and run an event when form2 closes by using a FormCloseEventHandler. This updates some data on form1.

However, now I need form1 to run a formclose event handler from a different form3 that was launched in another part of the program, not form1.

How is this achievable? I thought of having a timer run every 10 seconds on form1 for a public flag set by the form3 formclose event, however this isn't the most elegant soution.

Comment: It is a typical Winforms trap.  Look around and observe how other programs work.  Do you have any at all that create three top-level windows?  Having to chain events isn't just awkward in your code, this kind of UI is a very awkward to the user as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have no Idea about what do you want to do exactly and why you are using this pattern, but here is a solution that satisfies what you need:

Create this method in `Form1`:

```
public void Form3_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Form 3 Closed");
}
```

In `Load` event of `Form3` you can do this:

```
var f1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
if(f1 !=null)
    this.FormClosed += f1.Form3_FormClosed;
```

Comment: Thank you. You solution works. But I guess I will need to rethink my interface design for future projects.

Comment: @nerdalert You are welcome:), Yes you are right and surely you can do it well:)

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't let forms show forms, because then it's hard to keep track of which forms are opened in your application and what their status is.

You need to implement a design pattern and introduce some class that handles the workflow between your forms. This class then decides which form to show in which occasion, and it can communicate between forms for example by using custom events.

Answer (score -1):

Executing long codes from an event handler is a typical [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_pushbutton).
Extract the code in `Form3.FormClose` into a common helper class so you can call it from different places.

Comment: Could you please explain the reason of the downvoting?